# Form validation for view helper elements zend fram

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework, filter

I want to add filters to form elements that is generated using [view-helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html), I make like this in index.phtml page

```
 <label>Email</label>
 <?php echo $this->formText('email', 'you@example.com', array('size' => 32)) ?>
```

I want to use this way of creating form elements because I make tabbed browsing,  and switch between tabs using jquery.

How can I add filter to this element against XSS and make regex for email format?

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>Email</label>
 <?php echo $this->formText('email', $this->escape('you@example.com'), array('size' => 32)) ?>
```

Read this http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html to chain validators and filters together to create a cage .